# Is unapply a word used in the english language?

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, word-request

Let's say I apply for a job. Then I have a change of mind and don't want to apply any longer. What is the correct word for this? Is it correct to use the word unapply?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Let's say I apply for a job. Then I have a change of mind and don't
> want to apply any longer. What is the correct word for this? Is it
> correct to use the word unapply?

No.  The correct expression is "to withdraw one's application".  You could write "I wish to withdraw my application" or "I no longer wish to proceed with my application".

Answer (score 5):

*Unapply* is used in English, but normally in a different context.

> **unapply** (third-person singular simple present unapplies, present participle unapplying, simple past and past participle unapplied)
>
> 1. (transitive, computing) To undo an apply operation; to remove (something previously applied).

https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/unapply

(note the "computing" context)

Here's an example from Stack Exchange: [Understand how to use apply and unapply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18468786/understand-how-to-use-apply-and-unapply)

As for the correct word, rjpond has it right: "withdraw my application"